# Styling the Outer Stroke of a path, with topoJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, topojson

I want to select the county borders in my visualization in order to style them. Right now, they are being styled by the "active" class, which is in the style tag:

http://blockbuilder.org/KingOfCramers/93fba8eb9f797c31fe4f1cab52a3ed32

[image]

The visualization is based on Mike Bostock's coropleth visualization, online here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606

My styles are already set up to select the path on a mouseover event, but something is not right. It's straightforward enough with `geoJSON`, but since the `topoJSON` files include `"arcs"` rather than just coordinates, I'm unsure how to selectively style those that are relevant to my mouseover event. Right now, the styling only highlights correctly certain parts of the path.

Comment: I didn't get the problem... can you better explain exactly what's the issue?

Comment: Are you referring to the un-even strokes right on the boundaries of some counties? If so, this is the order in which the geojson is drawn (its converted to geojson for drawing), you need to use .raise() on the  feature on mouseover. I believe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47316361/7106086) refers to the same issue (the second half of the answer is more relevant to the mouse over and even strokes)

Comment: That was my question, thank you Andrew. The "raise" function on each path works. I had no idea this function existed, very useful!!