# d3 topojson wont generate state outlines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, topojson

I am trying to generate outlines of states like in this tutorial http://duspviz.mit.edu/d3-workshop/mapping-data-with-d3/ towards the bottom. I've gotten everything else except for the states outlines.

```
var width2 = 720;
        var height2 = 500;

        var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
            .scale(1000)
            .translate([width2/2, height2/2]);

        var path = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(projection);

        var path2 = d3.geoPath()
            .projection(null);

        var svg = d3.select("#map2").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width2)
            .attr("height", height2);

        d3.queue()
            .defer(d3.json, "../data/us.json")
            .defer(d3.tsv, '../data/us_unemployment_2008.tsv')
            .await(ready);  //run ready when jsons are loaded

        function ready(error, us, us_unemployment_2008){
            if (error) throw error;

            var ratebyid = {};
            us_unemployment_2008.forEach(function(d){
                ratebyid[d.id] = +d.rate;
            });

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class','counties')
                .selectAll('path')
                .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
                .enter().append('path')
                .attr('d', path)
                .style('fill','white')
                .style('stroke','black');

            var color = d3.scaleThreshold()
                .domain([0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.10])
                .range(["#f2f0f7", "#dadaeb", "#bcbddc", "#9e9ac8", "#756bb1", "#54278f"]);

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class','counties')
                .selectAll('path')
                .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
                .enter().append('path')
                .attr('d', path)
                .style('fill', function(d){
                    return color(ratebyid[d.id]);
                });

            svg.append("path")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
                    return a.id !== b.id;
                }))
                .attr("class", "states")
                // .attr('fill','none')
                .attr("d", path);
        }
```

The fragmentation looks like this:

[image: The fragmentation looks like this]

I was able to fix this by adding `.attr('fill', 'none')` to the svg path. But now it does not show the white outline of the states like in the tutorial.

Now it looks like this:

[image: Now it looks like this]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

Comment: I'm not seeing where you specify a white border for the states, in addition to .attr("fill","none") what happens when you add .attr("stroke","white") to the path appended with topojson.mesh? While not your question, as for a fragmented mesh, this q and a might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45726130/d3-js-canvas-context-fill-wrong/45726635#45726635

Comment: Wow. I thought I had tried that.. That worked. Thanks!

Comment: As this was just a minor glitch there is not much to learn for the rest of the community. To keep things clean I'd like to suggest you either write a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or, preferably, delete this post altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `.attr("stroke","white")` did the trick. I thought I had tried this. From what I understand, this should not be necessary because the tutorial did not include this, but it works.

Comment: The example does do this, but it is easy to miss, it is in the css in the page head: `stroke: #fff;`