# Tooltip in d3/topojson choropleth map not working

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, topojson, choropleth

I have a [Choropleth map](https://codepen.io/TaraBryn/pen/efac1afee7a46530a47c198ae3ee0b99?editors=0110) where the tooltip is working for most of it, but the central states are now showing the tooltip...in face, they are not even running the mouseout callback function at all (tested with a console.log command).

At first I was using d3-tip, and that wasn't working, and it was the first time attempting it, so I thought I might be doing something wrong, so I opted to implement a standard div that toggles between `display: none` and `display: block` and when it still wasn't working, I threw in a console.log command to see if the callback function was running at all, and it's not. It's mostly an issue with Kansas, but some of the counties in the surrounding states are having problems too. and I know it's not an issue with the data set, because the [example](https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/EZKqza) given, which pulls from the same data set is working fine.

Here is the css for the tooltip:

```
#tooltip{
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(32,32,32,1);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  color: white
}
```

and the JS code:

```
$(function(){
  //svg setup
  const svgPadding = 60;
  const svgWidth = 1000;
  const svgHeight = 600;

  var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', svgWidth)
  .attr('height', svgHeight)
  .attr('id', 'map');

  function createChart(topData, eduData){
    //scales
    var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateBlues);
    var unitScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(eduData.map(e => e.bachelorsOrHigher)))
    .range([0,1])

    //map
    var path = d3.geoPath();
    svg.selectAll('.county')
    .data(topojson.feature(topData, topData.objects.counties).features)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'county')
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('data-fips', d=>d.id)
    .attr('eduIndex', d => eduData.map(e => e.fips).indexOf(d.id))
    .attr('data-education', function(){
      var index = d3.select(this).attr('eduIndex');
      if (index == -1)return 0;
      return  eduData[
        d3.select(this).
        attr('eduIndex')
      ]
        .bachelorsOrHigher
    })
    .attr('fill', function(){
      var value = d3.select(this).attr('data-education');
      return colorScale(unitScale(value));
    })
    .attr('stroke', function(){
      return d3.select(this).attr('fill');
    })
    .on('mouseover', function(d){
      var index = d3.select(this).attr('eduIndex');
      var education = d3.select(this).attr('data-education');
      var county = index == -1 ? 'unknown' : eduData[index].area_name;
      console.log(county)
      var tooltip = d3.select('#tooltip')
      .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 10 + 'px')
      .style('top', d3.event.pageY + 10 + 'px')
      .style('display', 'block')
      .attr('data-education', education)
      .html(`${county}: ${education}`)
    })
    .on('mouseout', ()=>d3.select('#tooltip').style('display', 'none'));

    svg.append('path')
    .datum(topojson.mesh(topData, topData.objects.states, (a,b)=>a.id!=b.id))
    .attr('d', path)
    .attr('fill', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', 0.4)

    //legend scale
    const legendWidth = 0.5 * svgWidth;
    const legendHeight = 30;
    const numCells = 1000;
    const cellWidth = legendWidth/numCells;
    const legendUnitScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, legendWidth])
    .range([0,1]);

    //legend
    var legend = svg.append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'legend')
    .attr('width', legendWidth)
    .attr('height', legendHeight)
    .attr('x', 0.5 * svgWidth)
    .attr('y', 0)
    for (let i = 0; i < numCells; i++){
      legend.append('rect')
      .attr('x', i * cellWidth)
      .attr('width', cellWidth)
      .attr('height', legendHeight - 10)
      .attr('fill', colorScale(legendUnitScale(i*cellWidth)))
    }
  }

  //json requests
 d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/no-stack-dub-sack/testable-projects-fcc/master/src/data/choropleth_map/counties.json')
    .then(function(topData){
    d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/no-stack-dub-sack/testable-projects-fcc/master/src/data/choropleth_map/for_user_education.json')
      .then(function(eduData){
      createChart(topData, eduData);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think there's a conflict between the state fill and the county fill. What happens when you set the state paths to fill =`'none'`

Comment: @RyanMorton Thank you for your suggestion. I originally set the fill to 'none' and it was throwing an error (and omitting it was making it fill in black) so I was most likely doing something wrong the first time I tried that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are applying a fill to the state mesh. Let's change the fill from `rgba(0,0,0,0)` to `rgba(10,10,10,0.1)`:

[image]

It should be clear now why the mouse interaction doesn't work in certain areas: the mesh is filled over top of it. Regardless of the fact you can't see the mesh due to it having 0 opacity, it still intercepts the mouse events.

The mesh is meant only to represent the borders: it is a collection of geojson lineStrings (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45726635/7106086) too). The mesh is not intended to be filled, it only should have a stroke.

If you change the mesh fill to `none`, or the pointer events of the mesh to none, then the map will work as expected.

Comment: yeah, it was originally  throwing an error when I put `fill` to `none` and it was filling in black when I omitted, so I was probably doing something wrong the first time, but it seems to be working now. Thanks! ^^